# Visual studio 2013 express not inserting default code block

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

Ok I have a computer that will not insert the default code statement when you double click on some controls. It works with some and not others.

It does it in a brand new solution.
It does it after a reset of the settings via tools > import/export settings > reset all settings.
It does it after a repair of visual studio via programs and features.

I am kinda stumped. Visual studio has only been on this computer for a couple days and was working at first.

In case it matters the language is VB.net and one of the controls giving us this issue more often than most is the serial port control.

Comment: Is the file read-only for any reason? Can't check out automatically in TFS? Code is running?

Comment: no.
tfs?
no.
Anything else I can check?